# Solving a second order differential equation given it has to satisfy a y condition?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

So the question is

What positive value of $k$ will allow $y = \sin(kt)$ to satisfy $$\frac {\mathrm d^{2} y}{\mathrm d x^{2}} + 16y = 0$$

If I subsitute $y = \sin(kt)$ the differential equation, and then integrate the new integral twice, I get

$$y^2=\displaystyle\frac{32}{k^2} \sin(kt)+C$$

which gives $\sin^2(kt)=\displaystyle\frac{32}{k^2} \sin(kt)+C$ which isn't super helpful.

Comment: Try $k = 4$. Also, what you have done doesn't make sense. Substituting $y = \sin(kt)$ into the ODE gives $$-k^{2} \sin(kt) + 16 \sin(kt) = 0$$ so I don't know what you mean by 'integrate the new integral twice'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is $$y(x)=C_1\sin(4x)+C_2\cos(4x)$$ since we have the ansatz $$y=e^{\lambda x}$$